# In BASH How Do I save up commands to be run after the rest of the script has completed?

Tags: bash, scripting, code-cleanup

I've got a bash script that walks through a >10 terabyte sized disk and when done, I'd like to issue what I think of as "cleanup commands" after the rest of the scripts activities have completed. ...I can only find the need to run these while walking the directory structure but have to run these final commands after all other processing is completed. ...I hope this it's clear what I want to do.

Of course I could drop them in a file and execute it just before exiting, but I was hoping for something that left no file-system footprints and just ran in memory since, given how long it may take to run, it may need to be interrupted and I don't want to have to deal with file-system cleanup after the fact. Perhaps I can use an array, then walk the array and de-reference the entries in the array and execute them one at a time? ... I don't have a lot of array experience in BASH, but my guess is that's the right basic direction. But, there may be something more intelligent to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a string array containing the commands and execute them?

Comment: Please add more specific examples. What kind of commands? What arguments to the commands? Why aren't you just adding them to the script you are executing against the target disk?

Comment: @Zucchini ...Yes, that's what I was thinking - it's the ONLY option I know of. Any others?

Comment: @dawg ...Not sure why you need specific examples, but you can just think of "touch" commands to reset some of the file system meta-data. And, if they're run at the wrong time - before everything else has finished, said meta-data gets modified and therefore invalid.

Comment: I'd imagine it's downvoted for the same reason as the close vote -- "needs details or clarity". Showing code for what you actually implemented, and explaining why that's not adequate as it stands (some inadequacy being necessary for the question to be about a problem "you actually face") might be a place to start improving it.

Comment: I downvoted and voted to close it. The reasons is as stated in my comments. It *super* unclear to me why 1) Why if you have a 10TB disc the file-system footprint is an issue ; 2) If you are already running a script to walk the 10TB, why wouldn't you add the clean-up in that script? (likely with an [exit trap](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/) 3) How are the contexts determined while walking the disk? It just seems that YOU have the answers and WE would only have guesses. Maybe approach with [How To Solve It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, Charles, for the comment. ... Frankly, I don't see why it needs any more details and it's it entirely clear? ... I mean, I hope we're not all idiots here! The exact code just doesn't matter and yes, I'm "really experiencing this"... What I've done is create my own faster disk cloning tool that uses many concurrent threads of rsync as a single-threaded copy of a 16T disk takes days but it can be done in a few hours if you saturate the I/O system, hence the "trashing of the file system meta-data" I spoke of in a comment.

Comment: @RichardT, ...it would be helpful to try to isolate _the problem you're having with bash itself_ from the context that's leading you to have that problem. There's no reason for the question to go into the disk thrashing. There's _lots_ of reason to go into what code you currently wrote and why that code isn't good enough as it already is (meaning, the narrow, specific problem it has). If you didn't know how to trigger the run-on-exit part, f/e, that's a narrow problem (that's probably already asked-and-answered elsewhere in our knowledge base).

Comment: @dawg Thanks for replying, dawg. ...If you put the touch statements in-line, and the next thread updates the same directory, the accessed time stamps are trashed. So, you either save the touch commands for the end or you have to go back through the whole damned disk just doing the touches. AND, the locations change because the code does various levels of rsyncing based on the size of various chunks of directory tree - no two disks are alike!

Comment: ...similarly, if you don't know how to escape values to make them `eval`-safe, that's another straightforward, clear question that's already asked-and-answered. But right now we don't know where you're hung up, so we can't taylor to focus on it, or determine whether the sticking point is duplicative of something already in the knowledge base.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ...I TRULY don't understand this: "But right now we don't know where you're hung up". I was very clear: How can I "store up" some commands to be run at a later time without writing them to disk, keeping it in memory? ...How is that not clear?

Comment: @RichardT: This has the *bones* of being a great question: *How do I add dynamic Bash commands to a script process that is running concurrent rsync commands against a large disk tree. I need to restore some altered metadata with commands such as touch XXX YYY that is run at the point of ZZZ. What is the best way to a) generate the commands as the disk is traversed; 2)  keep those commands without using a tmp file and 3) execute those commands at ZZZ point? Here is what I have tried so far _____*

Comment: @dawg Thanks again for the comment. I'm all for improvement, both of myself and this site. I simply didn't see the need for the extra verbosity, given that "if it goes without saying, don't", and that "the shorter the writing the better" (so long as clarity / content isn't lost). ... Are you suggesting I update the question along the lines you propose?

Comment: My suggestions would make your question significantly shorter and more clear. That is what I am suggesting. It would be unique approach to building a dynamic `trap` on exit. Not that is *sturdy* but unique!

Comment: @dawg Thanks again, dawg; I will do so as soon as I have some time - perhaps in an hour or three... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation might look like:

```
cleanup_cmds=( )            # initialize an empty array
on_cleanup() {              # define a function to use to append to that array
  local cmd_str
  printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"
  cleanup_cmds+=( cmd_str )
}
run_cleanup_cmds() {        # define a function to run everything in that array
  for cmd in "${cleanup_cmds[@]}"; do
    eval "$cmd"
  done
}
trap run_cleanup_cmds EXIT  # run everything in the array on exit
```

Whenever you want to add an item to the array, it's as simple as:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp -t foobar.XXXXXX)
on_cleanup rm -f -- "$tmpfile"
```

...and the item is added, in such a way as to function correctly even if the command contains quotes/spaces/etc in the parameters.

Comment: That's great, thanks!